# На тестовом домене не работает google карта

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Карта по ссылке http://denispyb.beget.tech/#map

Вот HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Вот JS

```
<script type="module">
    let map;
    async function initMap() {
      const position = { lat: -26.344, lng: 141.031 };
      const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
      const { AdvancedMarkerView } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
      map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: position,
        mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID",
      });
      const marker = new AdvancedMarkerView({
        map: map,
        position: position,
        title: "Uluru",
      });
    }
    initMap();
</script>

<script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg", v: "beta"});</script>
```

На сайте пишет ошибка и не запускается google карта. Как это исправить?

Comment: А в настройках самой гугл карты вы какие выставили? Пробела в том что вы скорее всего домен неверно прописали в настройках самой гугл карты и он на это ругается `Error: Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError`

Comment: я скопировал все от сюда https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map?hl=ru#maps_add_map-javascript

Comment: Вы же ключ к карте получали через google cloud, я про 3-й шаг

Comment: Вообще я нечего не делал с этим. Просто скопировал код с документации

Comment: А ну поэтому и ругается, гугл карты нужно регистрировать получать АПИ ключ, настроить домен, если все эти шаги не сделать то и загружаться карты не будут. Альтернатива этому, использовать Яндекс карты, и не требует вводить данные карты. Использовать Яндекс карты можно совершенно бесплатно если суточный лимит не превышает 25000 запросов

Comment: Раз бесплатная заказчик согласится)) Спасибо!

Comment: Да я тоже так думаю) Пожалуйста! :)